# Error [972] [42000]: ORA-00972: identifier is too long. How can I insert this BLOB files data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert this data in this table, one of the columns (PHOTO) is for BLOB files, when I run this query I get an error SQL Error [972] [42000]: ORA-00972: identifier is too long. How can I insert this BLOB files data? I know identifiers are not allowed to exceed 30 characters in length, but this is the reference to the pictures that I need, so how do I solve this?

"INSERT INTO IDB.COM_MAINADVERT_TB (ID,CATEGORY_ID,USERNAME,EMAIL,IS_ACTIVE,UPDATED_ON,UPDATED_BY,CREATED_ON,PHOTO,DESCRIPTION,MIMETYPE,FILENAME,IMAGE_LAST_UPDATE,IMAGE_SIZE) VALUES
(70010,2100,'SESH','sellyh19@gmail.com',NULL,NULL,NULL,TIMESTAMP'2011-01-06 13:13:53.0',HEXTORAW(''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''),'Price giving ceremony. At Safari Hotel on 22 dec 2011','image/pjpeg','Hydrangeas.jpg',NULL,595284);"

Comment: I have cut out a big part of the BLOB file data, because of stackoverflow word limit.

Comment: I don't think that there is any connection to `psql` or DBeaver. Writing BLOBs in Oracle is difficult. Perform a web search, there are tons of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes (not double quotes or two single quotes) around string literals and split the string into multiple string literals each up to 4000 bytes and concatenate then all to a CLOB (either use `TO_CLOB` on the first 4000 byte literal or use `EMPTY_CLOB()` at the start).

```sql
INSERT INTO IDB.COM_MAINADVERT_TB (
 
  ID,CATEGORY_ID,USERNAME,EMAIL,IS_ACTIVE,UPDATED_ON,UPDATED_BY,CREATED_ON,
  PHOTO,
  DESCRIPTION,MIMETYPE,FILENAME,IMAGE_LAST_UPDATE,IMAGE_SIZE
) VALUES (
  70010,2100,'SESH','sellyh19@gmail.com',NULL,NULL,NULL,TIMESTAMP'2011-01-06 13:13:53.0',
  HEXTORAW(
    EMPTY_CLOB()
    || '0123456789ABCDEF...' -- Up to 4000 bytes
    || '0123456789ABCDEF...' -- Up to 4000 bytes
    || '0123456789ABCDEF...' -- Up to 4000 bytes
    || '0123456789ABCDEF...' -- Up to 4000 bytes
    || '0123456789ABCDEF...' -- Up to 4000 bytes
  ),
  'Price giving ceremony. At Safari Hotel on 22 dec 2011', 'image/pjpeg', 'Hydrangeas.jpg', NULL, 595284
);
```

Alternatively, load the BLOB from a file into a PL/SQL variable and then use the PL/SQL variable in the query.

Comment: I have followed your example, I'm not sure if I did it correctly. But I am still getting an error (SQL Error [907] [42000]: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis), where did I go wrong?

Comment: @MishaRukazo I have no idea because I cannot see your code.

Comment: Getting error-ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, where did I go wrong?

INSERT INTO IDB.COM_MAINADVERT_TB (ID,CATEGORY_ID,USERNAME,EMAIL,IS_ACTIVE,UPDATED_ON,UPDATED_BY,CREATED_ON,PHOTO,DESCRIPTION,MIMETYPE,FILENAME,IMAGE_LAST_UPDATE,IMAGE_SIZE)
VALUES
    (
    70010,2100,'SESH','sellyh19@gmail.com',NULL,NULL,NULL,TIMESTAMP'2011-01-06 13:13:53.0',
    HEXTORAW(
    EMPTY_CLOB()
    ||'FFD8FF2010000...'
    ||'FFE110C9D000...'
    ||'EA1C0007...'
||'CE900400300...'
||'FFD9),
    'Price giving ceremony. At Safari Hotel on 22 dec 2011','image/pjpeg','Hydrangeas.jpg',NULL,595284);

Comment: @MishaRukazo `||'FFD9` does not have a closing single quote before the `)`.